# Getting Flow warning messages with Reducer

Tags: flowtype, typing, react-context

Using the React Context API, I've built this reducer:

```
export const usersReducer = (state: UsersState, action: UsersAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_MODAL: {
      return {
        ...state,
        isModalOpen: !state.isModalOpen
      };
    }

    case CANCEL_REQUEST: {
      return {
        ...state,
        isCancelRequest: action.payload
      };
    }

    case UPDATE_COMPANY: {
      return {
        ...state,
        companyId: action.payload
      };
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

The associated Actions look like this:

```
// Note: `ActionType` = `string`
export const TOGGLE_MODAL: ActionType = 'TOGGLE_MODAL';
export const CANCEL_REQUEST: ActionType = 'CANCEL_REQUEST';
export const UPDATE_COMPANY: ActionType = 'UPDATE_COMPANY';

type ToggleModalAction = {type: typeof TOGGLE_MODAL};
type CancelRequestAction = {type: typeof CANCEL_REQUEST, payload: boolean};
type UpdateCompanyAction = {type: typeof UPDATE_COMPANY, payload: number};

export type UsersAction = 
     | ToggleModalAction
     | CancelRequestAction
     | UpdateCompanyAction;
```

On the two `action.payload` instances, Flow is saying this:

```
Cannot get `action.payload` because property `payload` is missing in  `ToggleModalAction`
```

I thought the way I defined my 3 "...Action" types, I could include `payload` where warranted and exclude it where it's not needed, like in `ToggleModalAction`.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing `typeof TOGGLE_MODAL`, etc., the `type` key of your `UsersAction` type will always be `string`. What you need in order to get type help from Flow's [disjoint unions](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#disjoint-unions-) is the string literals themselves:

```js
type ToggleModalAction = {type: 'TOGGLE_MODAL'};
type CancelRequestAction = {type: 'CANCEL_REQUEST', payload: boolean};
type UpdateCompanyAction = {type: 'UPDATE_COMPANY', payload: number};
```

Comment: I think the `case` statements also need to change to use the string literals (e.g., `'TOGGLE_MODAL'`) instead of the assigned variable. This is a documented "wishlist" issue https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/8056.

Comment: I see.  I've tried it just now and that does correct the problem.  However, using string literals completely defeats the purpose of introducing constants, in order to reduce the chance of a typo.

Put another way, I feel that I'm altering my coding practices (making it worse) simply to get Flow to work properly.

What are your thoughts about this, @Ross Allen?

Comment: @user11307804 Ah hah, as I suspected, this is a flaw with Flow.  I'm going to stick with the constants because it is a fundamentally better way then introducing string literals everywhere.

Comment: The use of constants was accepted as a best practice because JS had no type checker. When your code is covered by Flow, there's no need to pull out constants like this. If you provide a string that is not part of the union, Flow will tell you. https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAggIgFSgXigbwFBSsAhgcygC4oByYARlIBospdioA7AVwFsAjCAJwwF8oAH3R08hEuQBMNOh0YBnYNwCWTfPwwYAZiyYBjYMoD2THBEWSAFAA9G8BAEpGrTjxHZ5Ad2XA9ACxsAOjEHTGxsPVx5aHIqIjpwqD0TeSMAGwhAtKN8S1jSBwBuBPDuCGAWblMKYsTI6LJgaXjEiJT0zOzcqQLa1rKKqqhJPoiomOAAZlIW1uSmVIysnLyAVSYy3H9cDgyAQgODgpLsAcrTSdGoABMILVwWNOBZxLOhgBY6Pn4gA

Comment: I'd reverse your statement and in the current world of Flow + TypeScript I'd say, introducing constants completely defeats the purpose of using a type system! If your code is typechecked then there's no need to pull out these constants and import them across various modules. Use string literals everywhere, and the type system will give you typecheck-time feedback rather than having to wait for the execution-time feedback of using constants.